# Memory management with std::vector and boost::thread

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, stdvector, eigen

Suppose I have the following code

```
class simple_class
{
public:
    simple_class() { }

    void start()
    {
        boost::thread simple_thread(&simple_class::expand,this);
    }

    void expand()
    {
        while(1)
        {
            this->private_vector.push_back((int)1);
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> private_vector;
};

int main()
{
    simple_class* obj1 = new simple_class();
    simple_class* obj2 = new simple_class();
    obj1->start();
    obj2->start();
    while(1) {}
}
```

Obviously this program will run out of memory at some point and should throw a `std::bad_alloc`. But my question is the following:

1. Is there a case that private_vector of obj1 will be over-written by private_vector of obj2 before that happen? Is there a way to be protected from this?
2. If i enforce the private_vector in the class to be aligned in memory (like Eigen does with its matrices) when we define EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_NEW_OPERATOR will this change things wrt to question 1?

Comment: If instead of pushing elements to private_vector i keep resizing an Eigen matrices and making it bigger? Or if i declare new Eigen matrices inside Expand? I know it shouldn't but i ask is there a possibility it can happen or a way to prevent it?

Comment: I don't know how the Eigen allocators work, but if they allowed stomping on unrelated memory (since the `vector`s are two distinct objects) that would be pretty abysmal.

Comment: private_vector objects of the two classes will never overwrite or get overwritten by the other. This is because the the memory that has been allocated to one object, will not be allocated to another object, until the first object frees it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not normally one to answer questions, but I am almost 100% sure the answer to this is:

1. "No." You're using the new operator and an STL object. The biggest thing you have to worry about, as you pointed out, is quickly running out of memory.
2. No again. I don't know anything about Eigen matrices, but memory alignment will be determined by the OS and the compiler, not by the language.